# Is there any method to check the POSSIBILITY of converting a string to an Integer type?

Tags: apex

Is there any way or method to check the POSSIBILITY of converting a string to an Integer type, or in other words: how do I know if an exception will be thrown when converting a string to an Integer? My idea is to use a try/catch block, and I want to know if there is a less cumbersome way. In Apex Salesforce!

Here is my code, are there any more accurate analogues:

```
public static boolean isConvertPoss(string str)
    {
            try
            {
                integer number=Integer.valueOf(str);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid the possible expense of throwing an exception, you can use a Pattern (regular expression):

```
public static boolean isConvertPoss(string str)
  if(str != null) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile('[-+]?\\d{1,10}');
    try {
      return p.matcher(str).matches() && Integer.valueOf(str) != null;
    } catch(Exception e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

We first check if str is not null, then we create a pattern that allows a optional leading positive/negative indicator followed by at least one digit.

Edit: based on comments, I realized we should probably do a sanity check that there are no more than ten digits, and afterwards try a conversion in case it's outside the binary range of *-2<sup>31</sup>* to *2<sup>31</sup>-1*.

Comment: @PhilW thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: I think it makes sense to anchor the pattern to the (start and) end of input to avoid false matches if there are extraneous characters.

Comment: ... presuming that the number is not too big resp. Long for an Integer ;-)

Comment: @PhilW matches() must match the entire string, while find() will search within a string to find each group that matches.

Comment: @FelixvanHove True. I tried not to read too much into the situation at hand. Depending on the situation, a range-limited regex wrapped in a try-catch might be a better idea to avoid an excessively complicated regex while still providing reasonable performance.

Comment: @sfdcfox that's absolutely true, so anchoring is unnecessary. I still find it reassuring to use anchors to simply be entirely explicit with the pattern, regardless of usage, but that's a personal choice.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I really just felt like being nitpicking ;-)

Comment: Is a leading positive indicator actually allowed? Weird.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It is indeed. I actually tested it to confirm, so I technically learned something new today (or remembered what I forgot).

Comment: For me, the above solution is enough, many thanks to all of you

Comment: In fact if one doesn't mind much the difference between Long and Integer, one could redraft the check with String methods isNumeric and charAt() - the latter in consideration of '-' and '+'. What all of this demonstrates is that a try-catch around Integer.valueOf() is best! :-)